# How to check for a change from Nil in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, null

So I was pretty sure this was going to work...

```
expect { file.send(:on_io) {} }.to change{
  file.io.class
}.from( NilClass ).to( File )
```

but it fails with this message...

```
result should have initially been NilClass, but was NilClass
```

*Hu?*

First off, why does this return as a failure? Secondly, I know normally you can check for nil with `be_nil` by using the `nil?` method. Is there some special way to do this with a `from().to()` in RSpec?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should work:

```
expect { file.send(:on_io) {} }.to change{
  file.io
}.from(NilClass).to(File)
```

rspec will use `===` to compare the value in `from` and `to`. But `===` is not commutative, and when called on a class it will check if its argument is an instance of the class. So:

```
NilClass === NilClass
#=> false
```

Because NilClass is not an instance of NilClass. On the other hand,

```
NilClass === nil
#=> true
nil === nil
#=> true
nil === NilClass
#=> false
```

Because nil is an instance of NilClass, nil is equal to nil, but nil is not equal to NilClass.

You could also write your test in that way:

```
expect { file.send(:on_io) {} }.to change{
  file.io
}.from(nil).to(File)
```

which I think is the most readable.

Comment: if `nil === NilClass` returns false, wouldn't `file.io === File` return false as well(assuming `file.io` is an instance of `File`)?

Comment: But the test will be `File === file.io`, that's the whole point :)

Comment: Ahh ok, the arguments in `to` and `from` are compared to the returned value rather than visa versa. Makes sense. Thank you that explained everything well!